# Определить родительский класс и его потомков (минимум 3)

Tags: java, ооп, наследование, полиморфизм

Помогите определить классы, исходя из этого задания (**родительский и его потомки**):

> Определить множество и сумму налогов физического лица за год с
>   учётом доходов с основного и дополнительного мест работы, авторских
>   наград, продажи имущества, получения в подарок денежных сумм и имущества,
>   переводов из-за границы, льготы на детей и материальную помощь. Провести
>   сортировку налогов по их сумме.
>
> В ходе написания программы мы должны получить навыки в использовании механизма *наследования* и *полиморфизма*.

Так вот, где здесь кроется *полиморфизм*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно такая заготовка:

Класс Person, у него есть поле со списком поступлений List

```
public class Person {
  List<Income> incomes = new ArrayList<>();;
  public BigDecimal calculateTax() {
    BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    incomes.forEach(i -> result.add(i.calculateTax())); //<-полиморфизм
    return result;
  }
  //Методы добавления, удаления, изменения, получения Income
}
```

Income - интерфейс поступлений. У Income есть несколько реализаций: доход по основному месту работы, доход по доп.месту работы и прочее.
реализации Income должны имплементить метод расчета налога (могут быть разные формулы для разных типов поступлений).

```
public interface Income {
  BigDecimal calculateTax();
  void addOutcome(Outcome outcome); //добавить вычет
  void removeOutcome(Outcome outcome); //удалить вычет
  void setSum(BigDecimal sum);
}
```

С льготами: они вроде должны привязываться к источнику дохода - например, льгота на детей предоставляется по основному месту работы. Т.е. в Income добавляем так же список вычетов по налогу, который будет учавствовать в расчетах налогов.

```
public interface Outcome {
  void setSum(BigDecimal sum);
  BigDecimal getSum();
}
```

UPD: Абстрактная реализация Income:

```
public abstract class AbstractIncome implements Income {

  protected List<Outcome> outcomes = new ArrayList<>();
  protected BigDecimal sum;

  @Override
  public void addOutcome(Outcome outcome) {
    outcomes.add(outcome);
  }

  @Override
  public void removeOutcome(Outcome outcome) {
    outcomes.remove(outcome);
  }

  @Override
  public void setSum(BigDecimal sum) {
    this.sum = sum;
  }
}
```

UPD2:
Класс Person - это налогоплательщик. Income - интерфейс описывающий доход Person. Т.к. доходы могут облагаться разными налогами, то создаем несколько разных реализаций Income. Различаются они только формулой расчета налога, поэтому общие методы выносим в абстрактный класс AbstractIncome. На каждый тип начислений создаем отдельный класс-наслединк AbstractIncome. Например так:

```
public class WorkIncome extends AbstractIncome {
  @Override
  public BigDecimal calculateTax() {
    //Считаем вычет по налогу
    BigDecimal vychet = outcomes.stream()
        .map(o -> o.getSum())
        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
    //Считаем налог
    BigDecimal result = sum.multiply(new BigDecimal(0.13)).subtract(vychet);
    //Если результа больше 0, то возвращаем его, иначе возвращаем 0 
    return result.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0 ? result : BigDecimal.ZERO;
  }
}
```

Такие классы создаем для разных видов начислений: где-то может быть налог 13%, где-то 25%, где-то может быть фиксированная сумма налога. Это наследование.

PS Кроме этого Вам надо написать реализацию(и) интерфейса Outcome.

Использоваться будет примерно так:

```
//Создаем налогоплательщика
Person person = new Person();
//доход по основному месту работы
Income workIncome = new WorkIncome();
workIncome.setSum(new BigDecimal(100000));
//вычет на детей
Outcome childOutcome = new ChildOutcome();
childOutcome.setSum(new BigDecimal(4000));
workIncome.addOutcome(childOutcome);
//авторские
Income avtorIncome = new AvtorIncome();
avtorIncome.setSum(new BigDecimal(20000));
//добавляем доходы
person.addIncome(workIncome);
person.addIncome(avtorIncome);
//Вычисляем итоговый доход
System.out.println(person.calculateTax());
```

Comment: А наследование здесь не пройдет никак? задание о наследовании...

Comment: У интерфейса Income проще сделать абстрактную реализацию 


class AbstractIncome implements Income {}. 


В ней реализовать три метода addOutcome(), removeOutcome() и setSum(), а метод calculateTax() оставить абстрактным. Его реализовывать в наследниках AbstractIncome  Вот вам и наследование.

Comment: AbstractIncome - ?

Comment: Добавил в ответ.

Comment: а какие будут наследники Abstractincome?  извините, я чего-то в это задание не могу вьехать

Comment: ах да, а у класса Person могут быть наследники?

Comment: Вы, я так думаю, не захотите, НО не могли бы Вы поподробнее всё расписать?

Comment: Добавил в ответ. Надеюсь поможет.

Comment: Большое спасибо!